# Using multiple condition in when clause of drools rule engine version 7.X

Tags: drools

rule drl file in drools version 3 is given below, now we are upgrading to drools version 7.69

```
package rules.event   
dialect "java"`                                                     

rule "TASK_ARC_CIFF01_XMIT01_EXCEPTION_1000"                                  
when                                                                  
message : Message( product == "ARC", subtask == "MOVE01" ) ;
then                                                                  
exception.evaluate("1000",message);                           
mq.notify(exception,message);end                                    

                                                                        
//VMS message translation rules

rule "VMS_TRANSLATION"                                         
when  
    message : 
    Message(( product == "ISIXSR", subtask == "BLDPZ1" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXSR", subtask == "ECPLD2" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXSL", subtask == "FILMV1" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXSL", subtask == "MOVE01" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXRL", subtask == "MOVE01" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXRR", subtask == "MOVE01" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXER", subtask == "VALID2" ) ||
    Message( product == "ISIXRR", subtask == "XRFMV1" ) )
 

then                                                                  
    vmstr.notify(message);                           
    end
```

Error: Above file gives error message

```
Drools Error- ERR 102 mismatched input ',' in drools rule at line
rule "VMS_TRANSLATION"                                         
 when                                                                  
  message :  Message(( product == "ISIXSR", subtask == "BLDPZ1" ) ||
```

Can you please suggest what changes needed according to drools version 7

Migrating drools 3 rule engine to drools 7.69 rule engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to use that rule, you need to use `&&` and not `,` for those conditions.

Eg.

```
Message( (product == "ISIXSR" && subtask == "BLDPZ1") || ...
```

---

That being said, whenever you find yourself writing "or" conditions in rules, it's a sure-fire sign that you should have 2 (or more) rules.

I would rewrite "VMS_TRANSLATION" like this:

```
rule "VMS_TRANSLATION - ISIXSR"
when
  message: Message( product == "ISIXSR", subtask in ("BLDPZ1", "ECPLD2"))
then
  vmstr.notify(message)
end

rule "VMS_TRANSLATION - ISIXSL"
when
  message: Message( product == "ISIXSL", subtask in ("FILMV1", "MOVE01"))
then
  vmstr.notify(message)
end

rule "VMS_TRANSLATION - ISIXRL"
when
  message: Message( product == "ISIXRL", subtask == "MOVE01" )
then
  vmstr.notify(message)
end

rule "VMS_TRANSLATION - ISIXRR"
when
  message: Message( product == "ISIXRR", subtask in ("MOVE01", "XRFMV1") )
then
  vmstr.notify(message)
end

rule "VMS_TRANSLATION - ISIXER"
when
  message: Message( product == "ISIXER", subtask == "VALID2" )
then
  vmstr.notify(message)
end
```

It's a lot clearer, and a lot easier to test this way too.